# Subversion & SVN+SSH Permissions

Tags: permissions, svn

I want to set up some Subversion repositories, to be accessed via SVN+SSH, so that each repository is owned by a different group and is only accessible for reading and writing by the group's members. This is what I did so far:

```
sudo addgroup myproject
sudo mkdir -p /svn/myproject
sudo svnadmin create /svn/myproject
sudo chown -R :myproject /svn/myproject
sudo chmod -R g+rws /svn/myproject
```

However, something with my setup is not working properly...

1. Even though `userone` is not a member of the `myproject` group, `userone` can checkout the whole repository. (Is this because `userone` is member of the `sudo` group?)
2. `usertwo` is a member of the `myproject` group, but cannot commit to the repository due to an error: `permission denied while accessing /svn/myproject/db/revprops/__something__/__something__`

Point 1) is an issue because it may mean everyone with shell access to the machine can checkout the code. Point 2) is problematic because a user with (apparently) the right permissions can't commit to the repository.

What am I doing wrong in this setup?

Answer (score 3):

> Even though userone is not a member of the myproject group, userone can checkout the whole repository.

The repositories are probably world-readable. You can change that by running

```
sudo chmod -R o-rws /svn/myproject
```

> (Is this because userone is member of the sudo group?)

No, membership of the `sudo` group just means that you can gain root privileges through `sudo`. SVN wouldn't take advantage of that. (But, more generally, if a user has root privileges on a machine, they can read anything on it, you can't stop them.)

> usertwo is a member of the myproject group, but cannot commit to the repository

What probably happened is that `userone` committed some new files to the repository and they end up owned by him and not writeable by the project group.

The usual solution to this is to make all the directories inside the project have the setgid bit set. That will force all files created inside them be owned by the project group.

```
sudo chmod -R g+s /svn/myproject
```

Then you also need to make sure that everyone's umask is set to 002, so that files will be group-writeable by default.

This all gets quite complicated, and fragile, so it may be easier to serve the SVN repository via `https` only.

Comment: You don't need to set everyone's umask to 002 if you enable ACLs on the filesystem and `sudo setfacl -Rm d:g::rwX,g::rwX repo_dir/db`